# How to include Definitely Typed library to my deno project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, deno

How do I use the deno's [node compatibility mode](https://deno.land/manual@v1.26.1/node/compatibility_mode) with definitely typed modules? I tried this but that didn't seem to work as intended.

```
/// <reference types='npm:@types/three' />
```

1. I simply want the types available globally within my project
2. I do not want three.js library included in my code, only types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Deno v`1.26.1`, TypeScript is not supported in Node compatibility mode. From the [Node Compatibility Mode](https://deno.land/manual@v1.26.1/node/compatibility_mode#typescript-support) page in the manual:

> ### TypeScript support
>
> Currently, the compatibility mode does not support TypeScript.
>
> In the upcoming releases we plan to add support for a `types` field in `package.json`, to automatically lookup types and use them during type checking.
>
> In the long term, we'd like to provide ability to consume TypeScript code authored for the Node runtime.

---

If you just want the types from `@types/three` in a normal Deno module, then simply import them like you normally would from a source which utilizes Deno's literal import specifier syntax (such as [esm.sh](https://esm.sh)):

```ts
import type { Vector3Tuple } from "https://esm.sh/@types/three/index.d.ts?pin=v96";

const triplet: Vector3Tuple = [2, 2, 2]; // ok
```

Or all of the types onto a namespace:

```ts
import type * as Three from "https://esm.sh/@types/three/index.d.ts?pin=v96";

const triplet: Three.Vector3Tuple = [2, 2, 2]; // ok
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. that's a pity. Do you have any other ideas on what would work in this situation?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74005494/how-to-include-definitely-typed-library-to-my-deno-project/74005693#comment130669158_74005693) @kemicofaghost Is your project using Node compat mode, or were you only asking about that because you wanted to use a types package from DT in a normal Deno module graph (not Node compat)? If using compat, TS is simply unsupported right now. If normal Deno, you can import type-only information from a CDN like `esm.sh`: `import * as Three from "https://esm.sh/@types/three/index.d.ts?pin=v96";`

Comment: The former. I just want to be able to use DT in a regular Deno project.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only solves part of my problem. I'd still like to call `new Three.Scene()`, but unfortunately it won't work like that. I think I need to change my approach to the issue.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74005494/how-to-include-definitely-typed-library-to-my-deno-project/74005693?noredirect=1#comment130670188_74005693) @kemicofaghost Your question is about **types**. If you want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about importing **values**, then you are welcome to do that!

Answer (score 5):

As of version 1.27

> Deno will now automatically pull in TypeScript types from npm packages that
> distribute types.
>
> For packages that don't distribute types, you can use a @deno-types
> directive above the import in order to specify the corresponding
> @types package if one exists:

```
// @deno-types="npm:@types/chalk@4"
import chalk from "npm:chalk@4";
```

[Deno 1.27: Type checking and LSP support](https://deno.com/blog/v1.27)

Answer (score 1):

I essentially wanted to use three.js types globally within my project, however even when importing only the types the bundled version includes various incomplete constants and functions which cause type errors.

Using jsejcksn's esm.sh idea, I've opted to do this in my `deps.ts` file:

```
// @deno-types='https://esm.sh/v96/@types/three@0.144.0/index.d.ts'
export * as THREE from "https://esm.sh/v96/three@0.144.0/es2022/three.js";
```

This unfortunately includes Three.js in my final bundle output, but at least it's properly typed when I use it.